# Custom C++ Iterator (Similar to std::find)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I need to create an iterator able to "find" a value base on input criteria. I am currently stumped on how I should approach this. (Custom vector class)

Here's my code for my iterator

```
class iterator {
    public:
      //Variables
      int _index;
      vector* _v;

      //Constructors
      iterator() : _index(0), _v(0) { }
      iterator(int index, vector * vec) : _index(index), _v(vec) { }

      //Functions
      iterator& operator=(const iterator& itr){
        _v = itr._v;
        _index = itr._index;
        return *this;
      }

      friend bool operator==(const iterator& itr_a, const iterator& itr_b){
        return (itr_a._index == itr_b._index && itr_a._v == itr_b._v);
      }

      friend bool operator!=(const iterator& itr_a, const iterator& itr_b){
        return !(itr_a == itr_b);
      }

      iterator& operator++ () { _index++; return *this; }
      iterator& operator++ (int) { _index++; return *this; }
      iterator& next() { _index++; return *this; }
      int& operator*() { return (*_v)[_index]; }
  };
```

Now this iterator code works then trying to use

```
    for(vector::iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); i++) std::cout << *i std::end;
```

Though now I need to create a "find" function in my main class (vector) that can wort with this following code

```
vector::iterator i = vec.find(5); //Prints out "5" x amount of times
for(; j != vec.end(); j.next()) std::cout << *j << std::endl;
```

The only issue I find confusing is, since in my iterator class next is classified as "add 1 to index", though if I return an iterator find, it's next would still be "add 1 to index" versus "find next value of element". 
How can I go about trying to achieve this? It feels like a super simple answer. (Note, yes this is a school assignment to replicate features of std::vector, I will template my code eventually, I want to make it work with default ints first)

Comment: Did you try using `std::find()`? It may "just work".

Comment: We need to not use anything in the STL library, it has to be manually done, which is why I said similar to std::find()

Comment: std::find is not an iterator. find **uses** iterators.